# two input variables in a simple bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write my first bat file. Sorry......

I need to input a source directory (dir) for  another bat file to find test files and a destination directory (log)  for the bat file to output its results.

The bat file that does the processing is called fits.bat.

```
-i  Indicates that a file or directory to process will follow
-o  Directs the FITS output to a file
```

I have this:

```
@echo off

cd c:\program files\fits\fits-0.8.0 

SET /P dir=enter directory of source files

SET /P log=enter directory for log files

fits.bat -i %dir -o %log

pause
```

But I get no output at all.

If I type individual commands in command prompt window , it works and files in dir folder are correctly read and output is sent to the log folder

Answer (score 2):

try this....

```
@echo off
cd c:\program files\fits\fits-0.8.0
set /p dir=enter directory of source files
set /p log=echo enter directory for log files
fits.bat -i %dir% -o %log%
pause
```

when you call variables you need a % in front and back

%VAR%

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround your two variables in percent signs:

```
@echo off
cd c:\program files\fits\fits-0.8.0
SET /P dir=enter directory of source files:
SET /P log=enter directory for log files:
fits.bat -i %dir% -o %log%
pause
```